# control animation with simplyscroll

Tags: jquery, animation, controls, simplyscroll

I would like to use this plugin: [simplyscroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/)

But I need to be able to pause and resume the animation from external buttons. Apparently, it has some methods like moveStop and moveResume but I can't make it work.

help please!

ps: I open to use another plugin, what I need is a continuous loop without pausing between slides and methods like play & pause

**EDIT**: found another [plugin](http://www.maaki.com/)!!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't found those methods at the docs page.

Comment: Found another [plugin](http://www.maaki.com/)!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [plugin](http://www.maaki.com/) does exactly what I need